# Lookup loop in PL/SQL to find a final value

Tags: sql, oracle

List item

I have the below list of initial values that I need to use to search for in a second List of Merges.

List of initial values:

```
5753
5275
2553
1111
1234
1236
1238
2562
7464
3224
```

List of Merges:

```
Loser      Winner 
1111       2222
3333       4444
1234       1235
2222       3333
1236       1237
1238       1239
```

Doing a first visual check, I can see that one the values from the initial list, ID 1111 becomes ID 2222 in the List of Merges. My issue is that this merge can have multiple levels, as the ID 2222 further becomes ID 3333 which itself then further becomes ID 4444. This list is in no particular order and it cannot be ordered as the IDs do not have an incremental hierarchy.

Basically, what I want is to create an SQL or PL/SQL query that assigns the final value for ID 1111, which should be ID 4444, irrespective of the order in the List of Merges. I know this can be easily done in Excel with a sequential vLookup, but not sure how it can be replicated in SQL.

Comment: "I have the ... list" What do you mean by a list? Is it values stored in rows of a table or are they stored in a collection or VARRAY?

Comment: It is a table in an oracle database. Both lists (tables) are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have the data in tables. If so, you can use a hierarchical query and filter on `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` to get the last level of the hierarchy and then join back to your list of values:

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 5753 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5275 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2553 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1236 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1238 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2562 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7464 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3224 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE merges ( Loser, Winner ) AS
SELECT 1111, 2222 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3333, 4444 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 1235 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2222, 3333 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1236, 1237 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1238, 1239 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT value,
       COALESCE( m.winner, value ) AS updated_value
FROM   test_data t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( loser ) AS loser,
                winner
         FROM   merges
         WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
         CONNECT BY PRIOR Winner = Loser
       ) m
       ON ( t.value = m.loser );
```

**Output**:

> ```
> VALUE | UPDATED_VALUE
> ----: | ------------:
>  1111 |          4444
>  1234 |          1235
>  1236 |          1237
>  1238 |          1239
>  2562 |          2562
>  7464 |          7464
>  5753 |          5753
>  5275 |          5275
>  2553 |          2553
>  3224 |          3224
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2d8d5dcaf75b6b4b73ccd87c607b2d19)*

Comment: That was it! I have just tested the code on my table (a much larger set of data than the sample I posted above) and it worked fully. Thank you MT0 for the very fast solution, you're a star!